# How to programmatically add Google Map to a FrameLayout

Tags: android, google-maps

I programmatically made a FrameLayout in a Java Class

```
FrameLayout mf = new FrameLayout(this);
mf.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 200));
layContent.addView(mf);
```

and I want use this FrameLayout for show GoogleMap, and this is my code for GoogleMap

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment =  SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
fm.beginTransaction().replace(xxxxxxx, supportMapFragment).commit();
```

If I use FrameLayout from .xml, we can add id in **replace(xxxxx**, but now I use FrameLayout programmatically, so how to add Fragment GoogleMap to FrameLayout programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xxxxxxx` is the ID of the FrameLayout in the View.

All View objects have a `getId()` method.

```
FrameLayout layout = new FrameLayout(this);
// Optional: layout.setId(<some positive value>);
layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 200));
layContent.addView(layout);

FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment =  SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
fm.beginTransaction().replace(layout.getId(), supportMapFragment).commit();
```

If you want to optionally set a View Id, from API level 17 and above, you can call

`View.generateViewId()`